# Screenshot every 5 or 10 min from rtsp source using ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Hello i try make script who get screenshot from ip camera every 5 or 10 min
this script is work

ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "$SOURCE"-vf fps=fps=1/20  -update 1 /picture1.jpg

But when i start script. It make one shot for 20 second. I need just one pictures and wanna script stop. 
I can make bash script to run script every 5 or 10 min. 
When start for 2 time script ask me to Overwrite and i need say Y. This is not good for me.

PS. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only one picture:

```
$ ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "$SOURCE" -frames 1 ./picture1.jpg
```

Comment: Yes this is work but can i say "y" when ask file is Overwrite ? delete before start script is not a options

Comment: Add `-y` before the output name.